# ScriptManager Conflicting with CustomValidator Client Validation Function

Tags: asp.net

For the clarity's sake, consider the following form that is based on a master page file.

**Form**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Secured_Test" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Test_SiteMaster.master" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainPageContent">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ClientValidate(source, args) 
    {
      alert('foo');
    }
  </script>

  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddl">
    <asp:ListItem Text="value 1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="value 2" Value="2" />
  </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" Text="Error!" ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate" />

  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="true" />

</asp:Content>
```

**My master page contains the following code:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

**Question / Issue:**

As is, `ClientValidate` function never fires. If I remove the ScriptManager call in my MasterPageFile, the code works as expected (`ClientValidate` is called and and an alert is issued when the button is clicked). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("method")){
string script=@"
   function ClientValidate(source, args) 
   {
      alert('foo');
   }";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(),  "method", script, true)
}
```

But in first you have to check error console of your browser. Maybe script which have been loaded by scriptreferrence throw an error and all other scripts execution  were stopped.

Comment: I will give this a shot - thanks! In the meantime, I have simply commented out the masterpage script reference.